# TypeError: datepicker_instActive is undefined in Jquery-ui Datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have built rails + angular app. In this I have used jquery-ui datepicker. I didn't find the solution why I get this error in console:

> TypeError: datepicker_instActive is undefined
>
> if(!$.datepicker._isDisabledDatepicker( datepicker_instActive.inline?
> datepicke...

in console.

My versions of `css` is `jQuery UI Datepicker 1.11.2`
and `js` is also the same.  `jQuery UI Datepicker 1.11.2`

And when I move my cursor on datepicker widget no.of same error counts are increased.

I think issue is in this function of Jquery:

```
function datepicker_handleMouseover() {
    if (!$.datepicker._isDisabledDatepicker( datepicker_instActive.inline? datepicker_instActive.dpDiv.parent()[0] : datepicker_instActive.input[0])) {
        $(this).parents(".ui-datepicker-calendar").find("a").removeClass("ui-state-hover");
        $(this).addClass("ui-state-hover");
        if (this.className.indexOf("ui-datepicker-prev") !== -1) {
            $(this).addClass("ui-datepicker-prev-hover");
        }
        if (this.className.indexOf("ui-datepicker-next") !== -1) {
            $(this).addClass("ui-datepicker-next-hover");
        }
    }
}
```

Do you have face same issue ever? Or any idea how can I resolve it. I have used bootstrap-modal popup and in that form I used datepicker.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue here in `jQuery UI 1.11.4`. We just created a bug ticket http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/14578 and hope this is fixed soon by the jQuery team.

**To workaround the problem**, just

- download *only* the datepicker component from the jQuery UI site via custom download (https://jqueryui.com/download/),
- Extract `jquery-ui.js` from the ZIP archive and rename it, e.g. `jquery-ui-1.11.4-datepicker-fix.js`
- embed the script right after your full jQuery UI script in your template(s), and
- add a null-check to the first line of function `datepicker_handleMouseover()` as follows:

  ```
  function datepicker_handleMouseover() {
      if (!datepicker_instActive || !$.datepicker._isDisabledDatepicker( datepicker_instActive.inline? datepicker_instActive.dpDiv.parent()[0] : datepicker_instActive.input[0])) {
      ...
  }
  ```

No further changes to your code should be required. The patch can easily be removed when the bug has been fixed by simply removing the script tag from your templates.

**Note that this workaround completely overwrites the original datepicker plugin**.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this error when I included jquery-ui twice. Removing either instance resolved it.

Answer (score 1):

After destroying a datepicker, calling `refresh` on another datepicker sets `datepicker_instActive` again, which might be a more acceptable workaround than modifying external plugin code:

```
// Delete a datepicker
$('#date1').datepicker('destroy');

// WORKAROUND: Refresh another datepicker until the following is fixed
// http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/14578
$('.hasDatepicker').last().datepicker('refresh');
```

[Here's an updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joeyespo/x85hfnxr/3/) from the ticket to demonstrate the workaround.